# Google Translation Api Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-translate, buttonclick

I tried this class on my onclick class for the button I created

```
public void translateText(){

    // Instantiates a client
    Translate translate = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setApiKey("MY API KEY IS HERE").build().getService();

    // The text to translate
    String text = "Hello, world!";

    // Translates some text into Russian
    Translation translation =
            translate.translate(
                    text,
                    Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
                    Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ru"));


    System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", text);
    translatedText.setText(translation.getTranslatedText());
    System.out.printf("Translation: %s%n", translation.getTranslatedText());

    }
```

But if doesn´t work. Some help needed.

Comment: Can you explain how it doesn't work?

Comment: The worst part of the program crashes and doesn't show the error. I am trying to make a translation app and I already included the library. Since the button has a onclick class I thought this code is only that i need but it closes the whole app.